# Cannot install some libraries from requirements.txt in IntellijIDEA

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, anaconda, python-3.6

In my Python project developed in IntellijIDEA, I have the file `requirements.txt` with the following content:

```
paho-mqtt==1.3.1
scipy=0.19.0
utm==0.4.2
pandas==0.22.0
shapely=1.3.3
pyproj=1.9.5.1
```

When I build the project, I get the error:

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - paho-mqtt==1.3.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

I was able to build this project on another laptop without any problem.

I am using Python 3.6 and the Python SDK path is the following: `/Users/mimi/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like package is not available when you installed via `pip-install -r requirements.txt`

Maybe you can git clone package from github and install - https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#installation

Or using Anaconda:

`conda install -c wheeler-microfluidics paho-mqtt` (win)

`conda install -c lucaszw paho-mqtt`  (mac)

Comment: Since I have Mac, I tested `conda install -c lucaszw paho-mqtt`. But I get this error: `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - paho-mqtt
  - traitlets
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

Comment: I changed the system interpreter to another version of Python, and now all libraries mentioned in requirements.txt were properly installed.

Comment: Can you open terminal in (anaconda) environment and type next:

Comment: git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python.git,  cd paho.mqtt.python,  python setup.py install  (If you're using Python 3.X this should work). In python 2.7 conda install -c lucaszw paho-mqtt should be fine